# Randomize which element to appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have these `h1` elements that display a phrase before entering the website:

```
<h1 class="intro_text1" style="display: none;position: absolute; top:60%; left: 50%;font-size: 2em;font-family: 'Stylish', sans-serif;">Have you heard about the song of Ice and Fire?</h1>
<h1 class="intro_text2" style="display: none;position: absolute; top:40%; left: 50%;font-size: 2em;font-family: 'Stylish', sans-serif;">Test2?</h1>
```

and the jQuery to make them appear:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".intro_text1").fadeIn();
    $(".intro_text1").delay(3000).fadeOut();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".intro_text2").fadeIn();
    $(".intro_text2").delay(3000).fadeOut();
});
```

I would like to randomize which `h1` to appear everytime a user connects to the website, how can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some quick random number generation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let headingIn = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
  let headingOut = headingIn == 1 ? 2 : 1;
  $(".intro_text" + headingIn).fadeIn();
  $(".intro_text" + headingOut).delay(3000).fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly - but how would I customize the code if I had more phrases to implement, considering their class is always `intro_text3, intro_text4`, etc?

Comment: What would those do @cdxJava, more `fadeIn`, `fadeOut` etc? Also if my answer fixed your problem please accept it.